# for loop crashing... segFault c++

Tags: c++

I have a for loop that cycles through an array list of days and stores an int in variable num, when I cycle through the first 7 days, my program crashes, I want it to restart at day 1 and change to monkey '1'... but after the first loop it crashes.

What am I doing wrong?

**C++**

```
//*********************************************************************************************
//                               function prototype
//*********************************************************************************************
void collectFood(string days[]);



int main(){

    //array to hold week days
    string days[7] = {"Mon", "Tue", "Wen", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};

    collectFood(days);

}
//*********************************************************************************************
//                    function to collect foods amounts
//*********************************************************************************************
void collectFood(string days[]){    
    int num = 0;

    // for loop for each monkey
    for (int monkey=0; monkey < 3; monkey++){
        // for loop to take 7 days worth of food per monkey
        for (int day=0; day < sizeof(days); day++){
            cout << "Enter the pounds of food eaten by monkey " << monkey
            << " on " << days[day]  << ": ";
            cin >> num ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(days);`I'm fairly confident that doesn't mean what you think it does. On a 64bit platform that will be **8**; not 7 (and on a 32bit platform it will only be 4). You're using the size of a *pointer*, not the magnitude of your array.

Comment: Just omit the `7` in the declaration of days, later instead of `sizeof(days)` use `days->length()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculation of expected magnitude is not correct in the context you're using. A simple C-type array (which is what you have, regardless of the type within) expresses as a pointer-to-type when passed as a simple parameter.

Thus, this:

```
void collectFood(string days[])
```

is equivalent to this:

```
void collectFood(string *days)
```

and it becomes clearly evident that `sizeof(days)` is indeed the size of a *pointer* to `string`. On your platform I can probably safely assume you're compiling 64bit code, as a pointer in that context would be **eight** bytes, and thusly you would be exceeding your array's actual size by one element.

There are a multitude of ways to do this. You could simply declare an extra parameter to your `collectFood` function that describes the magnitude of the sequence.

```
void collectFood(string days[], size_t N)
```

and use `N` within your for-loop condition, invoking `collectFood` like this from `main()`:

```
collectFood(days, sizeof(days)/sizeof(*days));
```

An alternative would be a template that takes a non-typed parameter deduced from the array, which is passed by *reference*:

```
template<size_t N>
void collectFood(string (&days)[N])
{
   ...
}
```

and again, use `N` within the for-condition as the count limit. In this case the call from `main()` would remain as you have it now. `N` would be deduced by the call. As an added benefit, you cannot accidentally pass a raw pointer to this function; it *must* be a declared array type, or the magnitude cannot be deduced and the compiler will spew an error telling you so.

There are other ways, but the former of these, simply passing the length and declaring it as a formal parameter, is likely the easiest for you to understand.

Best of luck.

Comment: I will be honest, some of the phrases you used are out of my knowledge base. And I've realized that "sizeof()" does not infact do what I thought it did. I was under the impression for some reason that sizeof() would give me the length of the array, which is what I was going for. so heres what I do understand.... that "string *days" is a pointer which points to the location of the array, correct? what I am confused about is " the magnitude of the sequence" by declaring an extra parameter.... i also have no knowledge of templates, but understand the idea of what it is.

Comment: If I am just trying to use the length of my array "7", would there be a simpiler way? while what you showed me is probably proper and advance its just way out of my knowledge base. for instance i could simply replace sizeof(days) with "7" and it will do what I want it to, but I was trying to do it in such a way to pass the size of the array, for future use if the array was to change sizes and to have the knowledge base that if my array wasnt a set 7 days, i could use something the would determine the size of the array for the for loop, if that makes sense.

Comment: @waterunnr4 The simplest way is the *first* one I showed you, and is by far easiest to understand. As you become further experienced with C++ there will be more options exposed to you, such as the template method I showed. Eventually you'll likely move to `std::array<>`, `std::vector<>`, etc. It comes with time.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's your inner for loop when you're using sizeof(days).  When you pass the array to a function it only passes a pointer to the first element of the array, not the entire array.

You could fix this by adding a function parameter that tells you the size of the array or you could switch to using std::vector which has a size() method.  I'd personally go with std::vector.